# PHP: Explode using special characters

Tags: php, special-characters, explode

I'm working on a long string grabbed from a Session that uses "§" (Section sign) to group and divide different parts of the string.

Example: "ArticleID | Title | Date § ArticleID | Title | Date § ArticleID | Title | Date"

I want to put this into an array using:
`explode("§",$str);`

However, for some reason the character is totally ignored.

I have simply used a different character instead to get this working but why does PHP not recognise it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the file encoding. This § can be being passed to explode() as "\xA7", "\xA7\x00" or "\xC2\xA7" depending if the PHP file is encoded as ASCII, UNICODE or UTF-8 respectively.

Comment: What do you mean *Unicode **or** UTF-8*?  There is no such thing as encoded as Unicode.  This makes no sense.